# TYPO3: Issue with the install tool in 7.6.9

Tags: installation, typo3

I've installed the TYPO3 from scratch on an empty DB.

Everything worked fine until I reached the point where you have to create your first Backend user.
Well, I filled in the form and clicked "continue". Then, the page reloaded and nothing happened. Checking the DB showed me that the Backend user has been created, so I left the Install Tool and accessed the Backend via "domain.com/typo3". Logging in worked fine, as well.

But now, when I try to access the Install Tool in the BE (via the tab on the sidebar), it still wants me to create my first BE user. The installation process stays permanently on 80%.

I'm looking for a method to trick T3 to think that the installation process is finished, because it actually is.

The only thing I did differently than usually was to click on "Continue, I know what I'm doing" in the first step. T3 complained about the `always_populate_raw_post_data=-1` and I created a php.ini in the root directory to fix that and continued without checking because I thought it'd fix the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this setting in your LocalConfiguration.php:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['isInitialInstallationInProgress']
```

You have to set it to `false`.

Comment: Sorry, I've been on holiday last week. This solution works like a charm, thanks!